# How to change user's accesses depending on the authentication mechanism used in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, symfony-security

Suppose I have two authentication mechanisms. How do I allow/deny a user's access to content depending on which authentication mechanism they used to authenticate themselves.

For example, let's say I have:

- two type of users: `admin` and `user` such that all `admin`s are `user`s but `user`s are not `admin`s
- two authentication mechanisms: `admin_login` and `user_login`

I would like to make it so that an `admin` has to authenticate through `admin_login` in order to have admin accesses. This means he would be considered a regular `user` if he was authenticated through `user_login`.

I first thought about using firewall context,  but quickly realized it wasn't gonna work as I would need a firewall to support multiple contexts :

```yaml
# config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        admin:
            # ...
            context: // not currently supported
                - admin 
                - user
        user:
            # ...
            context: user
```

The other idea I came up with was creating a property called `is_allow_admin`  in the `User` class and using it to change the way the roles are retrieved by setting it in the  `admin_login` authenticator :

```php
// src/Entity/User.php

// ...
class User implements UserInterface
{
    // ...

    private $is_allow_admin = false;

    // ...

    public function setIsAllowAdmin(bool $is_allow_admin)
    {
        $this->is_allow_admin = $is_allow_admin ;
    }

    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        if (!$this->is_allow_admin) {
            return ['ROLE_USER'];
        }

        //...

        return $roles;
    }
    // ...
}
```

```php
// src/Security/AdminAuthenticator.php
class AdminAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    
    //...

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider): ?UserInterface
    {
        
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['username']);

        if (!$user) {

            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('username could not be found.');
        }
        $user->setIsAllowAdmin(true); // <-

        return $user;
    }

    //...

}
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. Everything goes smoothly with the authenticator, `onAuthenticationSuccess` is triggered. But somehow in the end, no user is authenticated.
I know it has to do with `$this->setIsAllowAdmin(true);` since it works correctly when I remove the line.

Is there another way to tackle this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Give you user's a Role (user or admin) and use the [Symfony Security Component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#denying-access-roles-and-other-authorization)

Comment: @DylanDelobel I'm already using Roles and the Security Component. Can you explain the idea you have in mind ?

Comment: `setIsAllowAdmin` is a `User` method, not an `Authenticator` method, you are calling it with `$this`. You might consider saving that information in the [`Token`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/1e3c87561cf13a290e8224bcfd7557155cc0cdf5/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/AbstractToken.php#L29) instead of the entity or implement a new `Token` type.

Comment: @msg the `$this->setIsAllowAdmin` call was a typo, thanks for pointing it out. I'm looking into Token attributes. Thanks!